# UIBarButtonItem override custom image color - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a huge problem with my `UIBarButtonItem`. I'd like to use a custom image depending on the torch state **(on/off)** but it's overriding my beautiful yellow icon to a blue "tasteless" icon.

Any idea or link that I missed about that?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: try adding **UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal** in  **imageWithRenderingMode**

Comment: use simply UIButton and set image in button.and set this button on navigation bar

Comment: ask clear question with necessary information so that some body can help!! `UIBarButtonItem` means what about you are asking? Navigation bar's button, tool bar's button , default back button of navigation? and you should post code snippet also!

Comment: How your adding UIBarButtonItem image programmatically  or storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"OnImage"];
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Depending on your condition you can change the image.

Comment: That's perfect ! Sorry for my lack of code during my explanation. I'd try to be a better user and to help other users on my own skills. Was my first time posting, and I enjoyed it

Comment: @BenoitThierry If this answer solved your problem, mark it as correct by clicking on tickmark icon.

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's documentation refer below method and it's available from iOS 7.0 and later:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithRenderingMode:(UIImageRenderingMode)renderingMode
```

To make compatible with below iOS 7.0 You have to check during the runtime this method is available or not.

```
UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourButifulImage"];
if ([yourImage respondsToSelector:@selector(isAvailabeImageWithRenderingMode:)]) 
{
   tabBarItem.image = [yourImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
} 
else 
{
   tabBarItem.image = yourImage;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: sorry @NSNoob by mistake i revert your edits, thanks for your edit.

Comment: You can always click rollback in edit history. If you want to restore that edit, you can do that right now. If not, well, it's your post, your choice, I just added URL formatting.